# CakePHP 2 in a subdirectory with ngix - 301 redirect

Tags: cakephp, nginx, configuration-files, http-status-code-301

I am having a really hard time getting nginx working with CakePHP in a subdirectory.

I'm using nginx because I am only familiar with Apache and I want to learn something new. My goal is to host CakePHP in a subdirectory.

My /etc/nginx/sites-available/default file looks like this:

```
server {

listen 0.0.0.0:80;
root /var/www/;
index index.html index.php;

include /etc/nginx/include/php;
error_page 404 = /404.html;

location / {
    root index.html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    autoindex on;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}

location /randodb {
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/randodb(.+)$ /randodb/app/webroot/$1 last;
        break;
    }
}

location /randodb/app/webroot {
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/randodb/app/webroot/(.+)$ /randodb/app/webroot/index.php?url=$1 last;
        break;
    }
  }
}

server {

listen 0.0.0.0:443;
root /var/www/;
index index.html index.php;

fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
include /etc/nginx/include/ssl;
include /etc/nginx/include/php;

error_page 404 = /404.html;


}
```

No matter what I do, any requests in the /randodb folder get a 301 redirect.

It always redirects me to `http://nginx-php-fastcgi/randodb/`

If you want to see this behavior in action: http://www.matgilbert.com/randodb

Answer (score 0):

First this is the only block you need

```
location ~ /randodb(.*) {
    root /var/www/randodb/app/webroot;
    try_files $1 $1/ /index.php?url=$1;
}
```

above in the `/` block, you specified `root index.html;` what is this supposed to do, cause I believe this is incorrect, root is supposed to be a directory.

About this block

```
fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
include /etc/nginx/include/ssl;
include /etc/nginx/include/php;
```

is php working ? never seen it before, are u using something different than fast-cgi or fpm?

then the ssl block, here's my ssl block on my server

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/name.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/name.key;
    server_name example.com
    location / {
        # the rest of my config
    }
}
```